# Installing MySQL without Root Access on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, root, mysql

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](http://www.bluecrownsoftware.com/article/271/Installing-MySQL-without-Root-Access-on-Linux).

1) I can't find CentOS listed as an operating system on the MySQL website. So I downloaded the mysql-8.0.11.tar.gz from the [MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/):

- MySQL Community Server 8.0.11
- Select operating System: Source Code
- Select OS Version: Generic Linux (Architecture Independent)

2) I unpacked everything into ~/mysql

3) From within ~/mysql, I tried to run:

```
./scripts/mysql_install_db --datadir=~/mysql/data
```

This gives the error message:

```
./scripts/mysql_install_db: No such file or directory
```

If I cd into scripts, I indeed find that mysql_install_db is missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't select source code.  Use fedora or "generic linux" as an OS

Comment: Each of these give me a binary. Afaik, I can't proceed installing these without having root access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe mysql_install_db is part of MySQL 8, it was deprecated in 5.7. You now use cmake to install and it can be installed without root in a local directory.

Follow the directions here: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/installing-source-distribution.html